# Algebraic surface with $0<b_1^2<b_2$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be a smooth projective minimal surface over an algebraically closed field.

Assume that any map $S\to C$ where $C$ is a curve of positive genus is constant.

Can the $l$-adic Betti numbers of $S$ satisfy $0<b_1^2<b_2$?

Comment: Yes. Take any irregular surface (so $b_1>0$), and blow up points till $b_2$ gets greater than $b_1^2$.

Comment: @abx thank you. Is there a minimal such surface?

Comment: Yes. Take an elliptic curve $E$ and a general hypersurface in $E\times \mathbb{P}^2$. Then $b_1=2$, but $b_2$ can be arbitrarily large.

Comment: Question revised in response to abx's helpful comments.

Comment: What about a general, smooth surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$ of degree at least $5$? The Picard number would be $1$ (Noether-Lefschetz) and it is simply connected, but $b_2$ can be arbitrarily large.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi so if it's simply connected do we have $b_1=0$?

Comment: @Francesco Polizzi: The OP asks for an inequality with $b_2$, not the Picard number.

Comment: Take an abelian variety $A$ of dimension 3, an ample divisor $D\subset A$, and a smooth surface $S\in\lvert nD\rvert$. Then $b_1=6$ but $b_2\rightarrow \infty $ with $n$.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread the question and I did not see the request $b_1 >0$.